# iconv doesn't work properly on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: character-encoding, windows-10, iconv

I want to convert legacy data from Windows 1253 to UTF-8 (without signature) on my Windows 10 Enterprise machine. I use iconv-1.9.2.win32 in the Windows Powershell:

```
iconv -f WINDOWS-1253 -t UTF-8 input.txt > output.txt
```

The output contains rather weird graphical symbols and not Greek.

If I redo the same using libiconv-1.9.2-1-bin I have the same problem. There is no problem on my Windows 7 machine.

Do you have an explanation? Might you recommend another solution or a tweak?

Comment: Compare the input bytes with the first column here http://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1253.TXT. Do any input bytes show #UNDEFINED in column 3? Is it plausible that the input is not encoded with WINDOWS-1253? Is � the weird graphical symbol? 
 [Edit] question to show output bytes in hex.

Comment: I found out in the meantime that iconv works properly when called in a command prompt (cmd.exe), but not in the Windows Powershell. The input is in any case WINDOWS-1253 encoded.

Comment: A sample snippet from the output is ''╬┐¤ü╬╣╬┐╬©╬¡¤ä╬À¤â╬À" which should be "οριοθέτηση".

Comment: `iconv`'s job is to convert bytes to bytes. It's the shell's job to render output bytes as text. Please use the divide and conquer debugging  strategy.